# SSAS - OLE DB error in establishing a connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, olap, ole

I have a problem when I try to process a SSAS project in Visual studio 2013 (sql server 2012) using Pubs data sample of Microsoft. Could anyone tell me how to resolv it? Thanks in advance!

> OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: A network-related or
>   instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection
>   to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if
>   instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow
>   remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.;
>   08001; Client unable to establish connection; 08001; Encryption not
>   supported on the client.; 08001.

Answer (score 10):

Change the Provider in the connection manager to OLE DB.

If that doesn't work, try restarting the SSAS service.

Comment: Thanks for your response, could you explain mor clearly how to change the provider?

Comment: Open up your data source designer; click the edit button under your connection string.  At the top of the window that opens up there's a dropdownlist labeled Provider.  Choose "Microsoft OLE Provider for SQL Server".

Comment: Did you ever try changing the provider?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have tried to change the provider but it's still not working :(

Comment: I just had the same problem as OP. Restarting the SSAS Database worked for me. 

Through Management Studio, log into Analysis Services and restart the SSAS database.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me today. It took 3 hours of trying everything I could to fix it and I wanted to share it so maybe someone else can be saved those hours. My solution is particular to my problem whereby I'm using impersonation to log into the server with a specific username and password.

In my case I had an SSAS tabular model with a connection to a remote Azure server. I am using Git on Azure DevOps for my source control and I had just moved over to a new development machine on our local network so I updated the remote repo with the latest version of the model, connected to the new dev machine and cloned the repo there. Then I tried to resume my work, but I was getting the same error you were: "OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible..." blah.

Anyway, I tried resetting the SSAS services, changing the connection provider, rolling back to a previous commit that I knew worked, etc. Nothing worked.

The problem was my impersonation settings!!! I have SSAS_Data_Model credentials created for this project so when I cloned the repo, for some reason the impersonation must not have come through with the password.

So, in Visual Studio, go to Tabular Model Explorer, click on Model -> Data Sources, Edit Connection -> Impersonation... -> and under 'Specific Windows user name and password', you need to re-enter the password for your username. This finally got it working again and I can import tables into my model once more.

Answer (score 0):

Try to test the connection when you provide appropriate server , database , provider. So you will be able to get the connection related problems there itself.
(data source designer -> connection string edit)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have tested those connections, but it's not working when I tried to process the project :(

Comment: by this do you mean that test connection is successful? is you database server and BIDS project execution server are different? If yes , then the user with which you are processing project , has access on the database server also if it is on different server

Answer (score 0):

My colleagues and I had this issue as well when building a cube. Tried all the settings and whatever solutions we could find online but none of them worked. Eventually changing the SSAS Connection from server name to IP resolved the issue (something like changing to 10.11.11.11 instead of AdventureWorks )