# OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error:

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I am trying to connect from my SSAS server to SQL through SSMS and the connection works fine when I test it. But when I am processing the cube, I am getting the below error message.

```
  OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.; 08001; Client unable to establish connection; 08001; Encryption not supported on the client.; 08001.
```

I have looked the other similar error message that was posted and tried the below options as per the suggestions.

[SSAS - OLE DB error in establishing a connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25409639/ssas-ole-db-error-in-establishing-a-connection)

```
1. Restart SSAS Service
2. Restart SSAS using local system
3. Trying to change the Provider to Native OLE DB\Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL server, but still I am getting the below error 

    OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error.
```

I am stuck with this for more than 3 days and not able to progress anything beyond. I tried all other Providers as well and still it doesn't work.

Additionally I made sure that the Windows account I am using in data source of SSAS server is having db_owner on the SQL data base.

Any help would be really appreciated to get me out of this.

Comment: Found this article http://geekswithblogs.net/LifeLongTechie/archive/2012/06/21/ssas-processing-error-client-unable-to-establish-connection-08001-encryption.aspx

Comment: as mentioned in my post tried this as well Steve.. but still no luck

Comment: Show us what your trying to do. Are you inside SSAS trying to process? Or are you in SSMS? Can you post some screendumps?

Comment: In order to process cubes you need to be enabled as a server administrator on the analysis services instance, otherwise you will not be able to process cubes, irrelevant of what your permissions are in the source database. Right click on the SSAS instance name in SSMS and look at Security; ensure you are added here. This will allow you to process the cubes.

Comment: @DimUser, yes I am the server admin on the SSAS server

Comment: @Thomas, yes, I am trying to process the cubes from SSMS, I am right clicking on app cubes under the cubes folder and clicking on process. I am not sure how to upload screen dumps here as I haven't done it earlier.

Comment: Is you services running? SQL Server, SQL Analysis Server Services? You just click the picture in edit mode and navigate your image file

Comment: yes my services are up and running.. I am working from a secure odc.. so couldn't send you screen dumps

Comment: Check the connection properties of the cube. There might be some user issues. Maybe the sql server doesn't accept remote connections or something?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get a solution for this upon trial and error method for selecting the below changes. I have tried to set the

```
   1. Provider as "Native OLE DB/Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server" 
   2. Changed the connection from Windows Authentication to SQL connection. 
   3. The type of Impersonate Account from Windows Authentication to Authenticate by Service Account.
```

Once the above settings were done, I was able to process the Cube.

Comment: Can you please  explain more the first step ?

Comment: @OmarKrichen: When you try to open and setup a datasource connection in your SSAS server to SQL server, you will have the option to select the Provider, I have selected - "Native OLE DB/Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server"